# physics engine - phase order and other general information

Tags: collision-detection, game-engine, physics, game-physics, physics-engine

I want to build my own 2D mini-physics engine, that will include(for now) rigid bodys, and constraints (joints, contacts, springs...).
And I've tried to figure out what is the right order of the phases, when I start a timestep,
when the the general phases are: Broadphase, Narrow phase(Collision Detection, and Contact generation),
Resolution (Constraints Solver), and the Integration - hope you can tell me the right order.

I allso have general questions about each phase:

**Narrow Phase** - When I've found a collision do I need to seperate the bodies after I've found the collision or just apply an impulse to their velocities in the resolution phase?

and if I'm using CCD(Continuous Collision Detection) for some bodies, what happand if I've found a collision (the earliest for object A) of a fast moving object A with other object B, and than I found that object B will collide with other object C before object he will collide with object A, do I need to go back to object A and looking for other collisions after the first collision I've found to him?

and if I'm using Contact Solver in my engine (in the constraints solver, I'll generat A Contact constraints for each collision, and I'll solve then all in the resolution phase, or I'll solve each contact right after I've found them in the narrow phase?

**Resolution** - Using a constaints Solver for the resolution phase is ok?
and what if by solving one constraint I'll solve other constraints or make more constraints? (Do I need to check after each constraints solving if it solves other constraints or make more?

**Intefration** - this is the part where I take all the information I gathered (impulses, forces..) and intefrate them to velocity and than to position with the integration method I chose?

A symplectic euler integration will be enough for my physics engine?

and I alsso saw in many physics engines, like box2D, they use iterations and let me chose the frequncy like here (notice I can change the iteration count (10) and the frequency (60.0 Hz)): [image]

What does this variables means? the iterations is how many times I recall the physics update(all the phases above) in each frame, or it just recall one phase like the narrow phase or somthing like that?
and the frequency variable let me chose how many frames there will be in one second?
correct me if i'm worng please.

all the qeustions above get me stack from learning because its basics things, and i didnt found a place that explain this things in a clean and strait forward

so thanks for anyone who will read all of that, and especially for anyone who will also help me with all of my questions :)

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic, so I removed that part to prevent the question from receiving close votes. Perhaps you may want to elaborate why you plan on writing your own physics engine? You seem to be stuck at the most basic aspects of a physics engine, so if your goal is anything other than really wanting to learn how to write a physics engine, you are probably better off using an existing physics engine, and perhaps modifying that. You may want to create some tests with Box2D  & Chipmunk and first try to understand what they really do, they're both open source.

Comment: ThiYou typed this in and not read a book. but it is interesting. but not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: @EdHeal Could you please elaborate on the reason for your close vote, and why it needed to be a "Off-Topic: Other.." reason?

Comment: Where is the programming bit.

I concur that this is an interesting question but not in the right forum

Comment: I want to write my own physics engine, beacause I dont like to use things I dont understand how they work and what they do, and  do all the hard work for me, but I want to do that hard work on my own.
I did read a lot before and I tried to read books (and I've learned the physics I need in order to write physics and joints physics, but I didnt find place that explains clearly and strait-forward the right way and the order to implement those in wariting and programming the actual physics engine, and altought its basic things, thats the only things that prevents me from moving forward.

Comment: @Ido finally finished editing my answer attempt (this question is Hardcore broad). btw the phase word use of yours is really misleading (or it is just me?) especially in title The first thing that evokes this in me was either some wavelet simulation of EM fields or complex frequency domain analysis ... if you change it slightly may be more relevant people will click on your question

Answer (score 0):

the order of your phases are not so important. Yes they do mess each other but any dis-function can be corrected by adjusting constants ...

1. **getting started**

you should start with object representation and visualization prior to any simulation code. You need to be able to visualize your stuff so you can see if is all OK or not

2. **object classes**

so create class(es) for all object types you want to support and add few basic interface functions (virtual base class is a good idea for future implementation) like:

- `load(file,ini,stream...),save(file,ini,stream...)`
- `draw(screen or render context),update(dt),bool colide(object)`,etc...

in time you will see exactly what you need to add ... They will be empty for now (instead the draw which you need to code...). You can also prepare few common physics variables (also as virtual) like position, speed, temperature,...

2. **base class**

it should be the encapsulation of your engine. It hold the lists of all the objects/stuff. Main interface with **GUI**/App. For more insight of what I mean by now look here [Drag&Drop editor in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20924609/2521214) you can use it as start point just add the physics **iteration/update** to it. Do not forget to implement the object interface into this main class like:

- `load(filename)` ... which load all the objects
- `draw(...)` ... which draws all the objects ...

3. **simulation**

start with this only if the above is already working. You need to take into account the accuracy and response time you want to achieve. The more fast object/processes are the higher simulation loop frequency you need. For mine simulations I usually use `1-100 ms` per iteration. For very fast simulation you can do `N` iterations per one timer call. That is the meaning of the **count** and **frequency**. Where frequency is the timer call speed your iteration loop is called and count (`N`) is the time step `dt` division so if `N=10` and `f=60Hz` it means you iterate `10` times every `1/60` seconds so it is the same as `N=1 f=600Hz` but at least in Windows timer resolution is `1 ms` and not very precise ether. So frequencies above `100 Hz` are unreliable. if you want to be even more precise you can measure the time by yourself via `PerformanceCounter` or `RDTSC` or any precise enough time **API** you have at disposal.

you can use **D'Alembert** principle (simple integration) for the simulation of motions the rest compute with known equations (do not know all of what you want to simulate). For example look here [simple mass points gravity simulation in 3D (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24753008/2521214)

if your code is well written you can parallelize the iteration loop but you have to take in mind that it can create few troubles like double collision reaction,etc

5. **collisions**

there are tons of stuff about this here on **SO/SE** so just search for it. I think you should look here: [simulation of particle collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26460129/2521214) to get the idea of multiple collisions handling.

**To get the idea here is example of how one of mine simulations looks like**

- [image: simple mass points simulation]

it uses all the stuff I wrote here about and in addition it uses a special class for bonds like springs or joints. This is how it looks like:

```
struct _bond
    {
    physics_point *pnt0,*pnt1;
    double l0,l1;
    int _beg0,_end0;
    int _beg1,_end1;
    List<int> depend0,depend1;
    int _computed;
    _bond()     {}
    _bond(_bond& a) { *this=a; }
    ~_bond()    {}
    _bond* operator = (const _bond *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //_bond* operator = (const _bond &a) { ...copy... return this; }
    };
List<_bond> bnds;
```

I could cover whole book with the stuff behind this but I am too lazy for that and also this site is not the right place for this so just in a hurry the important stuff is that each bond has it start and end object pointer (`pnt0,pnt1`) and during computations are filled the dependency lists (`depend0,depend1`).

- `depend0` for all consequential bonds from `pnt0` side
- `depend1` for all consequential bonds from `pnt1` side.

Then during each iteration is recursively updated all bonds to match the bond/collision conditions only when they all do then the positions are updated at once for all of them.

- `_computed flag` is just to announce that this bond is OK (conditions are met).

The rest is just temp variables to ease up the burden on the recursion heap/stack trashing

Here few related QAs (physics sims examples):

- [mass points with links (pendulums)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74628552/2521214)
- [gravity simulation with more complex collision test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71827702/2521214)
- [2D repel force field simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40827518/2521214)